# Refresh views within a function

Tags: java, android, view

I'm trying perform some steps inside a function on Android. I would like to tell to user what is happen in a specific moment without exit of my function. something like it:

```
public boolean updateServiceList() {
        LinearLayout start = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.start);
        LinearLayout major = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.major);
        TextView messenger = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messenger);
        Integer i = 0;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         boolean isOnline = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
         if(isOnline==false) {
             Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_btn);
             ProgressBar pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
                exit.setText("OK");
                exit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        gMain.this.finish();
                    }
                });
                pg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             messenger.setText(R.string.nointernet);


             while(isOnline==false) {
                                 i++;
                                 messenger.setText(messenger.getText()+"Try: "+ i.toString);
                                  boolean isOnline = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
                             }
             return false;

         } else {
             isOnline =  cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
             while (isOnline==false || 1==1) {
                 isOnline =  cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();

             }
    }

    return true;

}
```

My problem is in *"while(isOnline)"* where I can't see the update messages. I tried **invalidate()** and **postInvalidate()** there but no results. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I found the solution! There it is:
[How to refresh a TextView while looping in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425660/how-to-refresh-a-textview-while-looping-in-android)

The Rackers's answer:

```
public class myClass extends Activity{

private Handler mHandler;
private TextView text;
private int i;

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView01);
      i = 0;
      mHandler = new Handler();
      mHandler.post(mUpdate);

  }
```

private Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {

```
   text.setText("My number: " + i);
   i++;
   mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

}
```

};}

So, at my case I just call the others steps if the current is solved. If not, I just post the step again...

Comment: You should avoid writing `if(isOnline==false)`. Write `if(!isOnline)` instead.

Comment: I tried, but its working fine. My problem is that I have to wait the function finish before the Layout redraw... I would like to get the updates and send them to user before the loop end.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but may it be that it changes so fast it's not possible to see it? It's probably not leading anywhere, but could you try to use `if(i==1) {messenger.setText("Running..")}` instead and check what happens? On another note, how about using a progress bar?

Comment: I thought it too, but if it would true my program would return something in the screen, when I put the above code, the program freezes and don't update anything till my function finish.

There are more steps besides it, and to some it's important show the user the situation (sometimes I will do some questions too)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will not work.

When you call `messenger.setText()`, you think the screen is supposed to update right then. You are mistaken.

What really happens when you call `messenger.setText()` is that a message goes on a message queue, to be processed by the main application thread. That's the same thread you're tying up with your `while()` loop. While you are in that `while()` loop, your entire UI is frozen: no clicks, no updates, nothing.

I suggest that you get rid of the `while()` loop and move along with the rest of your app.

Comment: I can't move along if I haven't a internet connection. Besides, I've more steps like that and this steps will need show to user what the application is doing

I tried put the code in a runOnUiThread and new Thread, but I can't handling the views there. Always crash. I don't know more what to do.