# How to show status message on TextView in Main Activity?

Tags: java, android

I am newbie in android, in my android app, a main `Activity` class, which contains a `TextView` for displaying various status message from other classes.  I want to update `TextView` of main `Activity` with status values from other classes.  There is no direct connection between main activity class and other class. Is it possible in android ? if yes i am not aware to do it.  Kindly provide solution to do it

code snippets

```
//main activity
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    static String status = "Hello Friends";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    tv.setText(status);

        MyOtherClass myclass = new MyOtherClass();
        myclass.connect();
}
```

Other class is not an activity class

```
 // Other class
 public class MyOtherClass {
  public MyOtherClass(){
  }

   public void connect(){
    String strIP = Mtx.confRead("IPAddress");
    String strPort = Mtx.confRead("Port");

            String msg = "Connecting...";
            // i want to show value of msg varible in Textview of main activity from here
   }
```

thanking you

Comment: You need to refresh TextView to reflect the changed value.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. You can use TimerTask. Also you can try Handler class to refresh UI.

Comment: Here is a link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425660/how-to-refresh-a-textview-while-looping-in-android

Comment: please see my modified question

Comment: Hey Welcome........ Enjoy..... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a status instance field in your main activity

```
public static status = "initial status";
```

set it to the TextView

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youtTextViewId);

tv.setText(status);
```

and update it using values in other activities when they are called.

Comment: how refresh TextView from other class ?

Comment: tv.setText(newText) will do but then you must make the tv public static, call this when you change the status in someother activity, but if you are changing the status in some other activity and call main Activity again you dont need to do this, it automatically changes the TextView to new Text (i.e your updated status) because you are recreating the TextView but this time with an updated status Text

Comment: i am not telling to update he main Activity. If you go to an ActivityA from main Activity and change status there, it changes. But how do you know it got changed?? You will come back to the Main Activity right?? using an Intent. So when your are coming back to Main Activity it automatically gets updated. Only Thing you need to do in the Main Activity is to tv.setText(status) in the onCreate

Comment: please see my modified question

Comment: I used your solution with TimerTask mentioned by Krishna Suthar in comment section of the question to refresh the value, any way many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible you need to pass those status values from other classes and then use

```
         textView.setText(your_status);
```

values can be passed via intents through putExtra() and getExtra()

Comment: please see my modified question

Answer (score 1):

in first class send status like this

```
s=new Intent(this, nextClassName.class);
                    d=new Bundle();
                    d.putString("status", status);
                    s.putExtras(d);
                    startActivity(s);
```

then in the newClassName u can get it by this code

```
Intent t=getIntent();
    k=t.getExtras();
    status=k.getString("status");
```

the u can set Text of textview to status

```
textview.setText(status);
```

try this

Comment: can u review first snippet of your code, there is no relation between d and s

Comment: sorry i forgot to put the putExtras.. now i have added that.. :)

Comment: yeah u can use this.. in the previous class use bundle and putExtras to send status value to main class. then in main class us getExras method to retrieve that vlaue and then u can display it anywhere.

Comment: when u will go from previous class to main class it will transfer this value also. u can see there in code is startActivity. so once u tranfer control to main class the value also will be transferred.

Comment: please see my modified question

Answer (score 1):

if the other classes are activities that are started by ur activity, then use something like this

Main Activity

```
private void some_function() {
    startActivityForResult(intent_to_pass, SOME_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if((requestCode == SOME_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        // extract status from data and use setText() to set the new status
    }
}
```

Other Activity

```
// Prepare an intent, say result, with the status to be sent to main activity and use this to send back the new status
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
```

If the other classes are services and/or activities that are independent, then in Main Activity, use

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Extract new status from intent now and use it
}
```

In the other classes, simply start the main activity with an intent containing the new status. This ensures that if the main activity is already running, simply use the data in new intent received

EDIT (saw ur updates after posting):

if the other class is neither an activity nor a service, then u can do this:

when u create this class, pass the context of parent class (which can either be a service or an activity) to it and use this context to create an intent which is used with startActivity(). Or, simply communicate using BroadcastListeners. But i m not sure if this is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

u can do this by making these changes in your code

```
 public String connect(){
String strIP = Mtx.confRead("IPAddress");
String strPort = Mtx.confRead("Port");

        String msg = "Connecting...";
        return msg;

        // i want to show value of msg varible in Textview of main activity from here
```

}

and in main class

```
String status=myclass.connect();
textview.setText(status);
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

May be this could work.......

```
   //main activity
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

static String status = "Hello Friends";
static TextView tv;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
tv.setText(status);

    MyOtherClass myclass = new MyOtherClass();
    myclass.connect();
 }
```

In other class:

```
   // Other class
     public class MyOtherClass {
   public MyOtherClass(){
     }

       public void connect(){
      String strIP = Mtx.confRead("IPAddress");
        String strPort = Mtx.confRead("Port");

        String msg = "Connecting...";
          MainMenu.tv.setText(msg);
           }
```