# Timer not waiting on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I set up a timer to perform a task every 10 seconds within a loop. Also, this is inside a broadcastReceiver, not the MainActivity.

```
doSomething() {
  public void onSuccess(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length(); i++) {
      <wait 10 seconds>
      <show some message>
    } // if i == 3, the loop should take 30 seconds to perform
  }
}
```

I tried creating a new thread AND making a timer, but neither solution waits ten seconds for a task inside a loop. I have also tried doing `Thread.sleep(10000)` without creating a new thread, but this makes the main UI freeze for ten seconds before each task is performed. Could anyone lead me to the right direction?

**Edit:** this is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425660/how-to-refresh-a-textview-while-looping-in-android). My question, in other words, is that is it not possible to do a delayed task inside a loop? If so, why?

Comment: You need to switch your thinking to an event-based model.  Don't try to "pause" but rather *schedule* something to happen at a future time or after an interval.  If you have a lot of things which need to be done with pauses in between, you'll have to build a sort of "to-do list" and have your event method advance one step through it each time it runs, saving state information (ie, what do do next) persistently for the next execution.

Answer (score -1):

try this one count down timer    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't seem to work: the timer runs only ONCE at the start of for loop, so the entire loop starts after 10 seconds without delay in each subsequent task. The only thing that seems to work as intended is doing Thread.sleep(10000), which makes the main thread sleep for ten seconds for each iteration inside loop.