# How to stop while loop after back button is hit

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops, while-loop

I have tried so many ways of solving my problem, but still no success.I have a method, which returns me a string value and I am using it to update TextView on my screen like this: 
`outCPU.setText(getCpuInfo());`

Which would be fine, but I need to update this TextView until back button was pressed.

I guess i have need a while loop which starts after activity has been created and stops after back button was pressed. This loop should be in a new thread, because:- I have to load the activity first and execute the loop in another thread so the executing won't affect main thread and loading of the activity.

As I've already said, I don't know how to do this properly even though i have spent few hours on it.

Could someone show me an example how to get this done? Thanks...!!

### EDITED - WORKING:

```
private Handler mHandler;
private int i;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_systeminfo);

    outCPU = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outCPU);
    outMEM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outMEM);
    outTASKS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outTASKS);

    i = 0;
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.post(mUpdate);

}


private Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        outCPU.setText(getCpuInfo());
        outMEM.setText(getMemInfo());
        outTASKS.setText(getTasksInfo());
        i++;
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdate);
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.i("MSG", "Going back");

    finish();

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code including the loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425660/how-to-refresh-a-textview-while-looping-in-android

Comment: Maybe i'm stupid, but why do you have two nested threads ?

Comment: @JonasCz I don't understand it much, but I think it works like this: I need to create a thread which runs separately from main thread otherwise it stucks in a loop and activity isn't loaded and everything goes bad...also in that thread I can't make any changes to UI, so that's why is there runOnUiThread..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` to perform operations on UI Thread while being in a Thread. Or you can use 'my favorite' , the combination of `Thread` and [Handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html). To make sure the thread is stopped when back is pressed, you can use `handler.removeCallBacks(Runnable)` The following example could solve your problem:

```
//Global
Handler h = new Handler();

private static boolean flag = true;

public void updateTextView(){

 // call thread here
 h.post(thread);
}


  // take this thread out side so that it can be stopped with handler
 Thread thread = new Thread(){

 public void run(){

      while(flag)
      outCPU.setText(getCpuInfo());

    }

 }

public void onBackPressed(){

    flag = false;
    h.removeCallBacks(thread);
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I know, I'm using `Handler` to communicate between UI Thread and my Other Thread. For more info read the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Comment: doesn't work mate, it stucks in the while loop so neither the activity loads, just black screen

Comment: I had a solution with asynctask, but I didn't find a way how to apply loop on it, is there a way you can put doInBackground method into a loop?

Comment: @andrew looking at your code, I don't understand that why you're using a nested `Thread` ?? I've tested this scenario myself and it works perfectly fine. You cannot call `doInBackground()` in a loop.. and you certainly cannot update the UI from `doInBackground` either... you have to use my above example in your case. Use a `Handler` and `Thread`. And remove the nested `Thread` .

Comment: sorry, but could you explain what does exactly mean a "nested" thread? I've done few changes to my code, and it is working now. But still getting one issue, if I run this code as you can see it at the top of the page, android studio tells me, it's too much work on its main thread, I think I can solve this by using `new Asynctask.execute()` where I do my work to get CPU values, but when I go away from this activity and then go back, it itakes too much time to show some values via asyncask...don't you know why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a shared flag somewhere in your app:

```
private volatile boolean wasPressed = false;
```

In while loop, check this flag:

```
while (!wasPressed) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            outCPU.setText(getCpuInfo()); 
        }
    });
    // sleep for a while
}
```

On button click listener, switch `wasPressed` to `true`.

Comment: this way doesn't work, I am getting a black screen and I think it is because the while loop blocks the onCreate method when is executed..

Comment: *"i have need a while loop which starts after activity has been created and stops after back button was pressed. This loop should be in a new thread"*

Comment: In code, you posted as question update, I see creation of new thread, but not it's launch

Comment: and add some delay (e.g. `Thread.sleep(200)`) in while loop, otherwise your smartphone will turn into a grill ))